# How do I set alignment and restrict character length in an f string?

Tags: python, alignment, string-formatting, truncation

I am trying to output from a CSV reader a table with three columns. Each column is formatted differently. The first column has a maximum and minimum of 44 characters.

This is the print statement:

```
print(f"{row[1] :<44s} | {row[2] :>5} | {row[0]} {i[0]}")
```

The spacing is correct but this statement allows more than 44 characters.

The output I get is this:

```
Wonders of the World                         |     G | 16:40 20:00
Journey to Space                             | PG-13 | 19:00
Buffalo Bill And The Indians or Sitting Bull's History Lesson |    PG | 15:00 19:30
Adventure of Lewis and Clark                 | PG-13 | 10:00 14:30
```

The output should look like this:

```
Wonders of the World                         |     G | 16:40 20:00
Journey to Space                             | PG-13 | 19:00
Buffalo Bill And The Indians or Sitting Bull |    PG | 15:00 19:30
Adventure of Lewis and Clark                 | PG-13 | 10:00 14:30
```

Comment: Will you post an example of what the problem output looks like and what it should look like? I'm not entirely certain what you mean.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You do this in f-strings the same way as when calling the `.format` method on an ordinary string, because they use the same syntax for describing the format of each `{}` placeholder (f-strings allow for more complex computation of *what is put* in the placeholder, but it's formatted the same way). Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily limit char length with array slicing

```
strr = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry'
print(f"{strr[:44]} | {strr :>5}")
```

Output you'll see the first column will limit the length compared to the second one

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the prin | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
```

Note it is a bit unclear when you say that the first column has a minimum and a maximum of 44 characters, so this answer applies to if you have a maximum of 44, however it can be easily adjusted .